# symmetric group and the unitary group

Tags: linear-algebra

I read this passage in a book:
"We will use the canonical map $\tau$ from the symmetric group $S_n $ into the unitary group. It induces an isomorphism between $S_n$ and the Weyl group $W$ of $ U(n)$."
My question is: what is the canonical map from the symmetric group $ S_n$ into $ U(n)$. and how we get the isomorphism between $S_n$ and the Weyl group $W$ of $U(n)$.
Please who can answer this question

Comment: Let $b_1,...,b_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb C^n$ and $\varphi\in S_n$ a permutation. Then the map:
$$\Bbb C^n\to \Bbb C^n, \qquad \sum_i v_i b_i = \sum_i v_i b_{\varphi(i) }$$
is linear and unitary. This then defines a map $S_n\to U(n)$. Check all details necessary.

Comment: A permutation goes into the corresponding permutation matrix, zeros and ones are placed in the matrix with exactly one one in each row and in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical map from $S_n$ into $U(n)$ is the  map that maps $\sigma\in S_n$ into the linear automorphism of $\mathbb C^n$ which maps each vector $e_k$ from the canonical basis of $\mathbb C^n$ into $e_{\sigma(k)}$.

Comment: Thank you. How can this map induces an isomorphism from Sn to the weyl group W of U(n) ??

Comment: I don't know enough about Weyl groups in order to answer that. Perhaps that you could ask it as a new question.